# How to update the number of words/letters containing what user type in a search box in a list of words?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to the line above the widget box ("10 words in total") to be dynamically changing while user search for any letter/word, but could not succeed. The line should change with for example "2 words containing 'ab' ".

I used this line of code, but did not work:

```
var len= matches.length;
$("#WordCounter".text(len+"contain"+$("#typeahead").val()));
```

anyone know how to do that?

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs, q, cb) {
  return (function(q, cb, name) {
    var matches, substrRegex;
 
    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];
 
    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
 
    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
        
        matches.push(name(str));
  
      }
   
    });
 
    cb(matches);
  }(q, cb, function(res){return res}));


};
 
var states = [
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition",
    "adjustment",
    "advertisement",
];
 
  $.each(states, function (key, value) {
    $("#selection").append($("<option/>").val(key).text(value));
    });

 
$("#typeahead").on("input", function(e) {
  substringMatcher(states, e.target.value, function(results) {
    $("#selection").empty();
 
 
 
    $.map(results, function(value, index) {
  
  
    $("#selection").append($("<option/>", {
  
 
      "class":"results" + index,
   
      "html":value
   
  
 
  
     })) 
    })
  })
});

 
  $("#clearButton").click(results);
```

```css
html {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
     div{
        width:400px;
        margin:0px auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
    }
 select{
  width:400px;
        margin:40px auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body><div>Find: <input type="text" id="typeahead" /> 

<button id= "clearButton">Clear</button></div><br />


<div> <p id= "WordCounter">10 words in total</p></div>
  <select size="7" id="selection">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains wrong closing. It must be:

```
var len= matches.length;
$("#WordCounter").text(len + " contain " + $("#typeahead").val());
```

So the final html will be

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs, q, cb) {
  return (function(q, cb, name) {
    var matches, substrRegex;
 
    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];
 
    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
 
    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
        
        matches.push(name(str));
  
      }
   
    });
 
    cb(matches);
  }(q, cb, function(res){return res}));


};
 
var states = [
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition",
    "adjustment",
    "advertisement",
];
 
  $.each(states, function (key, value) {
    $("#selection").append($("<option/>").val(key).text(value));
    });

 
$("#typeahead").on("input", function(e) {
  substringMatcher(states, e.target.value, function(results) {
    var len= results.length;
    $("#WordCounter").text(len + " contain " + $("#typeahead").val());
    $("#selection").empty();
 
 
 
    $.map(results, function(value, index) {
  
  
    $("#selection").append($("<option/>", {
  
 
      "class":"results" + index,
   
      "html":value
   
  
 
  
     })) 
    })
  })
});

 
  $("#clearButton").click(results);
```

```css
html {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
     div{
        width:400px;
        margin:0px auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
    }
 select{
  width:400px;
        margin:40px auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body><div>Find: <input type="text" id="typeahead" /> 

<button id= "clearButton">Clear</button></div><br />


<div> <p id= "WordCounter">10 words in total</p></div>
  <select size="7" id="selection">
    </select>
```

Comment: yes, it works now. Thanks. Just wonder what is wrong with my clear button! I could not fixed it.  It has to clear the results and update the widget box to the first step; I mean showing all words again. Not sure where I am wrong!

Comment: You must supply a callback function on your click. In your case result is not define.